# want to find the files name that containes specified pattern in my bitbucket repo

Tags: python, java, linux

From many previous years, we have had massive Bitbucket repos that contained too large production files. We're trying to identify the names of the files that contain a certain pattern (regex pattern ).

Cloning the repo and using Linux grep is also a solution but it's too heavy work and not feasible at this moment.
If it is solved by directly providing the URL address of the repo and performing a pattern search within it and recording the name list of those files whose content matches the provided pattern (regex or any pattern) please let us know.